# Postgresql wal file apply to another cluster

Tags: database, postgresql

I have a one simple question about PostgreSQL databases. For example, I have A server postgres cluster and B postgres cluster. I copied data_directory of A server to data_directory of B server and then started B server with this datas and it works now normally. Now I don't want to create the Slave(Standby) server for always replicating. I just want to copy the WAL files from A server and apply this WAL files on B server manually. Can I do it with some way? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of.  You can put B into hot standby but just have no way for to successfully fetch WAL (neither primary_conninfo nor restore_command).  Then it would replay WAL whenever manually copied it into the pg_wal directory.  Or a different approach, specify a restore_command which tries to fetch data from an empty directory, then manually copy the WAL files into that directory whenever you want to.

But B will remain open only to read-only work if you do this.  If you want B to allow changes of its own as well as replay changes from A, then you will need to use logical replication, not physical replication. Logical replication can only be done by streaming, not by manual copying of WAL files.

Comment: Yes I can do that. That is no problem. But I put the WAL files from A to directory pg_wal of B, but after that how apply this WAL files to B when I will bring up the B. For example: Before backup on A i had a 3 tables like tab1, tab2, tab3, with this state I got a backup and send this backup files to B data_directory. After that I have created on A tab4, tab5 and switched the WAL files. That means there was generated a new WAL file in pg_wal of A. Then I can copy this new generated WAL file to B pg_wal directory. After that I want to apply last copied WAL file to B for creating tab4, tab5 on B

Comment: You should be copying the files out of A's wal *archive*, not out of its pg_wal.  In A's pg_wal, you might not know if it is an old file, the still active one, or an unused (recycled) one.  If you copied the still-active one, then you need to also copy all the ones that preceded it but which weren't yet copied to B.  (Plus you would need to copy that still-active one again once it is no longer active).  And there is nothing to prevent the files from being deleted/renamed before you've had a chance to copy them.